# Find standard deviation of a column in Pandas where each element is a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, std

I am trying to find the standard deviation of a column in a Pandas dataframe where each element is a numpy array. I want the final output to be a single numpy array where each value is the standard deviation of the corresponding values in the numpy arrays that make up the column, ie

```
row1 = [x1,x2,x3]
row2 = [y1,y2,y3]
row3 = [z1,z2,z3]

std(column) = [std of x1,y1,z1, std of x2,y2,z2, std of x3,y3,z3],
```

When I do the same operation with mean, it works perfectly:

```
df['DATA'].mean()
```

gives exactly the output I want, similar to what I describe above. However,

```
df['DATA'].std()
```

gives this error: `TypeError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Why doesn't `std` work the same way as `mean`? How can I make it work?

Comment: **df['DATA'].std()**  works if that is a pandas DataFrame. thing that you showed in your question corresponds to numpy array and not a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do so hopefully this helps.

```
stuff = [[1,2,3],[3,3,3],[4,3,5]]
import pandas as pd
stuff = pd.DataFrame(stuff)
stuff = stuff.rename(columns={0:'A',1:'B',2:'C'})
stuff.std()
```

Answer (score 0):

A relatively new feature in pandas can help here: `explode`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([np.array([1, 2, 3]),np.array([510, 3, 3])])
s.explode().reset_index().groupby('index').std()[0].values

# array([  1.        , 292.71658648])
```

It's available since version 0.25. [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)